# Console em windows forms application

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho uma classe aonde abre o console, mostra alguns dados e depois fecha, ao executar pela segunda vez (sem fechar o programa), ocorre uma exceção em `Console.WriteLine("")`

- Se executado uma vez, tudo funciona
- Se fechar e abrir o programa novamente, tudo funciona
- Se tentar executar a rotina `ExportarArquivos()` duas vezes, sem fechar a aplicação antes acontece o seguinte erro:

> Erro: Identificador inválido.
>
> ```
> StackTrace:em System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>  em System.IO.__ConsoleStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
> em System.IO.StreamWriter.Flush(Boolean flushStream, Boolean flushEncoder)
> em System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count)
> em System.IO.TextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
> em System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value)
> em System.Console.WriteLine(String value)`
> ```

Classe:

```
public static class Exportar
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool AllocConsole();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern bool FreeConsole();


    public static void ExportarArquivos()
    {
        bool aux = AllocConsole();
        Console.WriteLine(""); //ocorre a exceção aqui (na segunda vez), e aux == true neste ponto.
        Console.WriteLine("Gerando arquivos...");

        //Trabalha um pouco

        Console.WriteLine("");
        Console.WriteLine("Pressione qualquer tecla para sair");

        Console.ReadKey();
        FreeConsole();

    }

}
```

Alguém sabe o que pode estar causando isto?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deve ser porque você está declarando duas vezes seguidas uma variável com o `AllocConsole()`, crie uma condição para evitar isso. Primeiro, declare um verificador booleano (como variável global, não dentro do método):

```
private bool isConsoleVisible = false;
```

e depois, manuseie essa condição:

```
public static void ExportarArquivos()
{
    if (isConsoleVisible == false) {
         AllocConsole(); // não precisa criar uma variável para isso
         isConsoleVisible = true;
    } else {
         //FreeConsole(); // se quiser que ele se oculte, "descomente" isso
         //isConsoleVisible = false; // e isso também
    }

    Console.WriteLine(""); //ocorre a exceção aqui (na segunda vez), e aux == true neste ponto.
    Console.WriteLine("Gerando arquivos...");

    //Trabalha um pouco

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Pressione qualquer tecla para sair");

    Console.ReadKey();

    if (isConsoleVisible) FreeConsole; // se estiver visível, desapareça 

}
```

**[EDIT]**

Funcionou deste jeito, com uma dica retirada [daqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3571627/show-hide-the-console-window-of-a-c-sharp-console-application).

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0;
const int SW_SHOW = 5;

public static void ExportarArquivos()
{
    if (isConsoleVisible == false)
    {
        AllocConsole(); 
        isConsoleVisible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Clear();
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_SHOW);
    }

    //Trabalha um pouco

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Pressione qualquer tecla para sair");

    Console.ReadKey();

    ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow(), SW_HIDE);

}
```

Comment: Não testei isso mesmo, pensei que como eu "Liberava" com o FreeConsole, não haveria problema em chamar o "AllocConsole", vou testar amanhã, se funcionar marco como certo, mas já vai levar +1. Obrigado